# Redirect to Correct Pages

Tags: redirect

Very new to Magento, helping a friend of mine after the developer went AWOL and left unfinished site.

I made a whole bunch of fixes to pages and such, including correcting some URL Rewrites. All was working fine, took System and DB/Media backups and then I decided to attempt an upgrade to the latest version.. . I just upgraded to the latest stable version of all components and now the site is not redirecting to correct website/store for one of the two websites/stores.

OVERVIEW. There are three domains each with their own pages; .hk, .com as well as .ch in Chinese, English and German respectively. For .com and .hk, a language switcher is used which shows english or chinese, this works fine.

PROBLEM. When visiting .ch it redirects to .com and for the life of me I cannot figure what is making a redirect.

Any suggestions? Muchly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Open the backend of the website, go to `System > Configuration`, and click on `Web` item in the left menu.

In the top left corner of the content you can see a dropdown called `Current Configuration Scope`. Change it to the .ch store view, and then open the `Unsecure` and `Secure` tabs in the content view, and check the URL there.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your help! I checked each Configuration, they all have correct extension. For .CH both the Site and Store have .ch domain and the Base Link URL has {{unsecure_base_url}}. This appears to be the same for .com and .hk.

Comment: Another thing which may help you help me.. . Changing .com/contact-us to .ch/contact-us, redirects to the main page on .com. Before the upgrade this went to the equivalent page in relevant language under .ch. Hope this helps!